# Characterization of convolution operators via the Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, differential-operators, fourier-transform, convolution, tempered-distributions

Let $\mathcal{L}$ be a linear and continuous operator from the space of tempered distributions $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R})$ to itself. The Fourier transform of a tempered distribution $f$ is denoted by $\mathcal{F}f$ and the inverse Fourier transform by $\mathcal{F}^{-1}f$. I am wondering if the following conjecture is true, which would provide a characterization of convolution (i.e. shift-equivariant) operators.

**Conjecture:**
The operator $\mathcal{L}$ is shift-equivariant if and only if, for any $\varphi_1, \varphi_2 \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ with disjoint support (i.e., such that $\varphi_1 \times \varphi_2 = 0$), we have that
\begin{equation}
\langle \mathcal{L}  \{ \mathcal{F}\varphi_1 \} , \mathcal{L} \{ \mathcal{F}\varphi_2 \} \rangle = 0. 
\end{equation}

One side of the conjecture is clear. If $\mathcal{L}$ is shift equivariant, then it can be written as $\mathcal{L} f = h * f$ for some $h$ in the space $\mathcal{O}_{c}'(\mathbb{R})$ of rapidly decaying distributions. Therefore, using the properties of the Fourier transform, we have
\begin{equation}
\langle \mathcal{L}  \{ \mathcal{F}\varphi_1 \} , \mathcal{L} \{ \mathcal{F}\varphi_2  \} \rangle =
 \langle h * \mathcal{F}\varphi_1 ,h * \mathcal{F}\varphi_2 \rangle = \langle (\mathcal{F}^{-1} f ) \cdot  \varphi_1 ,(\mathcal{F}^{-1} f  ) \cdot  \varphi_2 \rangle = \langle (\mathcal{F}^{-1} f ) ,(\mathcal{F}^{-1} f  ) \cdot  \varphi_1 \cdot \varphi_2 \rangle = 0. 
\end{equation}
I am wondering if the converse of this result is true, leading to the proposed conjecture.

Comment: Shift-*invariant* means what I could call shift-*equivariant*, right, in the sense that the transform of the shift is the shift of the transform?

Comment: This is correct, it is more precise to talk about equivariance. I updated.

Comment: What about, for instance, $({\cal L}f)(x)=f(-x)$?

Comment: @MichaelRenardy, [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/373787/characterization-of-convolution-operators-via-the-fourier-transform#comment946193_373787) is not shift equivariant.

Comment: @MichaelRenardy Your counter-example can be solved by changing the statement to $\langle \mathcal{L}  \{ \mathcal{F}\varphi_1 \} , \mathcal{F}\varphi_2  \rangle = 0 
$. Next counter-example is $\cal{ Lf = F^{-1}( F(f)')}$.

Comment: @MichaelRenardy: true and simple, thanks. As reuns pointed out, your counter-example may be used to update the conjecture.

Comment: @reuns This works indeed. And actually anything of the form $\mathcal{F}^{-1} \{ h * \mathcal{F}\{f\} \}$ would, with $h$ a distribution whose support is a singleton (yours is $h = \delta'$). Therefore the conjecture is false. Thanks for your help.